# NER using Spacy Library(Probabilistic Analysis)

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

Objective: To increase the accuracy of Spacy NER Model with data input as newspaper article links particularly concerning Money Laundering and related keywords.

Is there any way through which I can come up with the probabilities with which a particular entity is classified as Name, Location, Organisation?

Comment: Sorry, your question is a duplicate. See this: [How to get spaCy NER probability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934523/how-to-get-spacy-ner-probability)